# Unable to link javascript file in express pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a **index.pug** with a drop down in it, i want to display the alert window when the user selects any value in the dropdown list. My **index.pug** and **commandLine.js** are in the same directory.But when i am selecting any value from drop down, the alert message is not displaying. I am using **onChange** function to call the **myFunction()** method. I tried lot of things but could not figure out the problem. I am not sure if `script(src="commandLine.js")`  is the correct way to link script in **.pug** file. Any help would really be appreciated.

**index.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script(src="commandLine.js")
  body
    h1 Intelligent State Space Pruning
    br
    form
      div
        label Samplertype
        select#samplertype(onchange='myFunction()')
          option(value='', selected='', disabled='', hidden='') Samplertype
          option(value='Monte Carlo Simulation ') Monte Carlo Simulation 
          option(value='Latin Hypercube Sampling') Latin Hypercube Sampling
          option(value='Descriptive Sampling ') Descriptive Sampling 
          option(value='Halton Sampling ')  Halton Sampling
```

**commandLine.js**

```
 function myFunction()
    {        
      alert('hi');
    }
```

Comment: You pug file is correct and the JS file also holds good. Most probably you don't have the compiled HTML and the 'commandLine.js' in the same directory(folder structure). Please check the path and set it right. Let me know whether that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function in assignment. You have to assign it.

```
select#samplertype(onchange='myFunction')
```

Answer (score 0):

using `script(type="text/javascript" scr='javascripts/commandLine.js')` solved the problem